# Getting time range from Kibana into painless scripted field

Tags: kibana, kibana-7

I'm trying to visualize application uptime data which is **not regular** but is only pushed to elasticsearch when an incident occurs. For the visualization I need the total number of days/hours user selected on the Kibana so that I can calculate and visualize total downtime in percentage for the selected duration.

Is there any way to get hold of the time range / date range selected by user from Kibana's 'Time Filter' component in a scripted field on Kibana?

Comment: Did you get some solution?

Comment: No, I didn't. Couldn't find anything on Elastic documentation as well.